# Order of the Stick comics, should we start asking here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should we start asking questions about the Order of the Stick universe on SciFi Stack Exchange?

The Order of the Stick consists of [webcomics](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots.html), [books](http://www.giantitp.com/Shop.html) and supplimentary material drawn by Rich Burlew aka the Giant on the Playground.  It is clearly a fantasy comic strip, so questions are on topic for the site, so we must accept any questions asked unless we specifically change the site policy.  But my question is not whether we can ask questions, but whether we *should* ask questions.

Now Order of the Stick has a [forum](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?22-The-Order-of-the-Stick), where fans already ask lots of questions and give answers.  On one hand, if we start asking questions here, we risk fragmenting the knowledge base, so in the future we'll have to search both the forums and this site to find answers.  This could be a reason why we need not want to ask these questions here, but instead only go to the forum.  On the other hand, the infrastructure of the OotS forum is not really good, even after the recent improvements that have re-enabled the search feature.  It's hard to find answers to questions there, and there are lots of duplicates for this reason.  Thus, asking questions on SciFi SE only could actually be an improvement.

Answer (score 8):

We already have [order-of-the-stick](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-of-the-stick) and [one question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/23654/1359) about it.

There's absolutely no reason to **not** ask them here.

The fact that there's another repository for Order of the Stick discussion is completely irrelevant.  If the existence of another repository for a given work or series of works were reason to keep questions off of our site, we would have no [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) questions ([Thanks to *Wookieepedia*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page)), no [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) questions ([Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Portal:Main)), or [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) questions ([Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/en-us)).

One of the purposes this site fulfills is to aggregate sources into a more comprehensive repository.  Existing external repositories, like Rich Burlew's OOTS forum, should be seen as resources that can be referenced in content here; not reasons to exclude content.

Comment: Was the slap in the face for Potterless intentional? (by equating it to other Wikias, instead of using HP Wikia in the pattern) :)

Comment: @DVK No, it was simply because I know the name of Pottermore, and not the name of the wikia.  TBH, I didn't know there **was** a distinct wikia for it.  For some reason, it seems particularly hard to get a chance to answer any Harry Potter questions on this site before a thoroughly awesome and comprehensive answer is slammed down, so it's not a topic I've had much cause to research :P

Comment: @Beoffet - Er.... sorry about crowding people out... But how could you have missed all the ranting and raving ... err... Well justified isues.... that Slytherincess did on the topic over the years (with me aiding)

Comment: @DVK I was too busy complaining about General Reference and why E.T. is in the Star Wars universe, I guess....